# Is there a callback function for Amazon SQS when new messages arrive?

Tags: c#, amazon-sqs

I'm new to Amazon SQS and I'm trying to implement it in one of my C# applications. From what I've seen so far from all the tutorials and blogs is that you keep polling the queue for messages and then if there are messages you loop through the queue and read each message and then process it.

I was thinking if there is any callback mechanism that is available. So that whenever a new message arrives in the queue the callback function is called?

Appreciate your help with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923586/trigger-lambda-when-new-message-arrives-to-sqs

Comment: @MitchWheat, appreciate your help on this. Are you saying I should create a lambda function and then use the lambda callback in my app. The lambda is doing nothing but a poll. I'm creating a windows service, I'd rather put a timer and poll the queue instead.